# When & whether to say El Maleh or Kaddish

Tags: tefilla, minhag, kaddish, yahrtzeit

I wish to honor the memory of family members (names & relationships unknown) who died when all the Jews were killed in the town from which my parents came.  The date this year comes out on 8/26.  Which is more appropriate, Kaddish or El Maleh?  If El Maleh, when during the service should it be said?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As this is for you a practical question, I really suggest you ask the rabbi of your local, orthodox synagogue. Besides always relying on your rabbi for practical questions rather than relying on answers you get here, there's a special consideration in the case of this question: Synagogues' practices differ w.r.t. the answer to your question, w.r.t. who says *kel male* (if that's what's to be said), and w.r.t. when you should say *kadish* (if that's what's to be said), and your local rabbi will make those calls for his own synagogue. Moreover, the rabbi may want to teach a *mishna* in public in memory of the departed, or the like.